# Putting Date and 1.month.ago together?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

How would I put `Date` and `1.month.ago` together when I have a date attribute called `:purchase_date` and want to put it inside a class method?

```
def self.last_month # Show only products of last month.
  where(:purchase_date => Date.today.1.month.ago.end_of_month..Date.1.month.ago.beginning_of_month)
end
```

console gives a syntax error and taking it away `Date.today` gives me blank results compared to my other method:

```
def self.this_month # Show only products of this month.
   where(:purchase_date => Date.today.beginning_of_month..Date.today.end_of_month)
end
```

Comment: I think just `1.month.ago` should be enough, you don't need Date.today, `1.month.ago` starts from today

Comment: @maprihoda, That's correct... go ahead and make it an answer so we can upvote you :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have mistake in your Date syntax, you might want to use something like this:

```
def self.last_month # Show only products of last month.
  where(:purchase_date => 1.month.ago.beginning_of_month..1.month.ago.end_of_month)
end

def self.this_month # Show only products of this month.
   where(:purchase_date => Date.today.beginning_of_month..Date.today.end_of_month)
end
```

Answer (score 16):

Just `1.month.ago` is enough, you don't need to prepend `Date.today` to `1.month.ago` because `1.month.ago` starts from today

Answer (score 0):

Maybe:

```
def self.this_month 
   where(:purchase_date =>(Date.today - 1.month)..Date.today
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If the future time needs to be farther out, like in the case of planned subscription orders, remember to use `.since`

```
def self.next_quarter    # Show only product order in the next 3 months
   where(:purchase_date => Date.today.beginning_of_month..3.months.since)
end
```